# How to change the Title of a view

Tags: iphone, xcode, button, label, title

So, I have two views and i want to give at my NavigationBar the name of a Label in my first view...

And i have an other, in my .xib, i have many button and Label and on the top a "+" button(in a Navigation Bar) (i'm not in a TableView) and my question is, when the first Label is completed, how when i press again the "+" button he change the second Label because the first Label =@"something else" and the same thing for the third...

Thanks a lot,
Alex

---

Thanks for your reply! i don't really speak english every day so... :p Anyway, my question was, when i click on a button (actually on my button I have 2 Labels, for the Firstname and the SecondName) and i want to give the title of the second view by the button pressed

Answer (score 0):

Your question is difficult to understand, but if all you need is how to set the title of the view in the current `UIViewController` you would use the `title` property.

```
[self setTitle:@"marvellous!"];
```

Comment: So does this button already have a IBAction method associated with it?